# Designing ShinyProxy Landing Page

Tags: html, r, docker, shiny, shinyproxy

I would like to know how I can customize the **Shinyproxy** landing page below.
I have read somewhere on the community that the *html file* can be found in this folder: `src/main/resources/templates` but I don’t have such folder in my Linux EC2 instance.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: maybe this helps: https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-config-examples/tree/master/04-custom-html-template